# Output of ++*p++

Tags: c

Can anyone explain me the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[]={10,20,30};
    int *p=a;
    ++*p++;
    printf("%d  %d  %d  %d",*p,a[0],a[1],a[2]);
}
```

> output is 20  11  20  30

Postfix incrementation has a higher precedence, so value of second index should have been incremented. Why is the value of first index incremented?

Comment: Why is this marked as duplicate? `p` and `*p` are *separate objects*, so the arguments about undefined behavior in the supposedly duplicate question don't apply.

Comment: Because postfix increment binds more tightly than dereference .

Comment: But I would not advise to use such a constructs for any purposes except educational ones..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Due to [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence),

`++*p++` is same as `++(*(p++))`.

That is equivalent to:

```
int* p1 = p++; // p1 points to a[0], p points to a[1]
++(*p1);       // Increments a[0]. It is now 11.
```

That explains the output.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the postfix operator returns the value before the increment. So the pointer is well incremented but the prefix operator still applies to the original pointer value.

Comment: That should be a comment.

Comment: @gsamaras, why would that be. I think this is exactly the fact the OP overlooked.

Comment: Well Jens, now that you edited the answer, it's better. (btw, I am not the downvoter).